# FullCalendar calendar doesn't display events when datetime format is 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Tags: symfony, events, datetime, format, fullcalendar

I am trying to make a FullCalendar calendar (that I have integrated in my application using Symfony2) display the loaded events from the database. In fact, when I have succeeded to do that using the code below which is the code of the functions which displays the events into the calendar:

```
public function LoadeventsAction() {
    $eventg = new eventsgroupe();
    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
    $token = $securityContext->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $id = $user->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $groupe=$this->getRequest('groupe'); 

    $idg = intval($groupe->attributes->get('id'));

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('e')
            ->from('IkprojGroupeBundle:eventsgroupe', 'e')
            ->where(' e.idEventGroupe = :ig');
    //$qb->setParameter("i", $id);
    $qb->setParameter("ig", $idg);
           $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $event = $query->getResult();



    $rows = array();
    foreach ($event as $obj) {
        $rows[] = array(
            'id' => $obj->getId(),
            'title' => "'" . $obj->getTitle() . "'",
            'start' => '"' . $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d') . '"',

            'end' => '"' . $obj->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d') . '"',

            'location' => '"' . $obj->getLocation(). '"',
            'description' => '"' . $obj->getDescription(). '"',
            //ajoute dees informations concernant levenement

        );
    }
    $response = new Response(json_encode($rows));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

This is the screenshot of the calendar that I have:
[image]
As you can notice above, the calendar is displayed in month view. Please focus on the events on the date: September 3rd 2014. Actually, when I click on the button "day" I obtain this view:
[image] 
As you can see at the screenshot above, all the events are "All day" events (which means events which last the whole day) whereas each one of them starts at a specific time and ends at a specific time as well. For example this is the record of the event "learning css" in the database (the last one):
[image]
As you see at the screenshot above, the datetime fields have this format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.
As I need time to display the events correctly in the day view (instead of being displayed as "all day" events), I changed the code of the function (I mean the first one I put in this post). Actually, I put `'start' => '"' . $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',` instead of `'start' => '"' . $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d') . '"',` and I put `'end' => '"' . $obj->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',` instead of `'end' => '"' . $obj->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d') . '"',` . So my new code is the following one:

```
class  EventgroupeController extends Controller
```

{

```
 public function LoadeventsAction() {
    $eventg = new eventsgroupe();
    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
    $token = $securityContext->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $id = $user->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $groupe=$this->getRequest('groupe'); 

    $idg = intval($groupe->attributes->get('id'));

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('e')
            ->from('IkprojGroupeBundle:eventsgroupe', 'e')
            ->where(' e.idEventGroupe = :ig');
    //$qb->setParameter("i", $id);
    $qb->setParameter("ig", $idg);
           $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $event = $query->getResult();



    $rows = array();
    foreach ($event as $obj) {
        $rows[] = array(
            'id' => $obj->getId(),
            'title' => "'" . $obj->getTitle() . "'",

            'start' => '"' . $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',

            'end' => '"' . $obj->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',
            'location' => '"' . $obj->getLocation(). '"',
            'description' => '"' . $obj->getDescription(). '"',
            //ajoute dees informations concernant levenement

        );
    }
    $response = new Response(json_encode($rows));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

Please focus on this code part:

```
foreach ($event as $obj) {
        $rows[] = array(
            'id' => $obj->getId(),
            'title' => "'" . $obj->getTitle() . "'",

            'start' => '"' . $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',

            'end' => '"' . $obj->getEnd()->`format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',`
            'location' => '"' . $obj->getLocation(). '"',
            'description' => '"' . $obj->getDescription(). '"',
            //ajoute dees informations concernant levenement

        );
    }
```

The problem is that since I have changed the code like that, the calendar doesn't display any events in any view. It is obvious that the issue comes from this code part: `format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',`. So my question is: what is the correct code? and how to deal with events that have datetime with this format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) for date format. If so, your issue is not with the dates, but with your object values. You don't need to add `"'"` at the beginning and end of each field.

Change your foreach to this:

```
foreach($event as $obj) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'id'          => $obj->getId(),
        'title'       => $obj->getTitle(),
        'start'       => $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'end'         => $obj->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'location'    => $obj->getLocation(),
        'description' => $obj->getDescription(),
        //ajoute dees informations concernant levenement
    );
}
```

If you append the `'`. your JSON object will have this format:

```
[{"id":"387","title":"'Learning PHP'","start":"\"2014-09-03 13:00:00\"","end":"\"2014-09-03 15:00:00\"","location":"\"at home\"","description":"\"learning classes lesson\""}]
```

And if you remove that character, it will have the following format (which works correctly):

```
[{"id":"387","title":"Learning PHP","start":"2014-09-03 13:00:00","end":"2014-09-03 15:00:00","location":"at home","description":"learning classes lesson"}]
```

Comment: Well, I tried the code that you suggested to me but there is no change, I mean that it is true that the calendar displays the events in the view of months, but when you have a look at the view of days (by clicking on the button "day") you will see that the events still be "all day" events (which mean all the events in a certain day last the whole day). So, it is probable that the problem still be with the format of datetime. Do you have any idea how to resolve that??

Comment: Please add to your question the result of `json_encode($rows)` (like I have in my answer) and the javascript that you are using to bind fullCalendar to your element. It might be something with the options of fullCalendar.

Comment: solved!!..I found the solution: I just set allDayDefault: false when initializing FullCalendar. Please have a look at this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424916/fullcalendar-showing-event-in-month-view-but-not-day-and-week-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424916/fullcalendar-showing-event-in-month-view-but-not-day-and-week-view)...By the way, I am so grateful for your code because it help me another problem in my whole code...Thanks a lot